# CSS Particular Cell In A Table -- Siny

Tags: css, r, shiny, styles

I have two tables on a tab in shiny

I want to apply conditional formatting to only one table on the tab but I am not too familiar with CSS styling. My current code applies the conditional formatting to all the tables. How can I get it to skip the first table and only style the second? If I change n+2 to n+3 it moves columns over for all the tables style but I am not sure how to move rows down. Any help would be great.

```
$('tbody tr td:nth-child(n+2)').each(function() {
var val = parseInt($(this).text());
```

Comment: what about `$('#tableid tbody tr td:nth-child(n+2)'`?

Comment: you're talking about styling with css, but showing a jquery code. Do you already have any css? Could you demo what you want with an example?

Comment: Ah sorry I am not too familiar with styling coding. @hubertL looks like it did the trick. Thank you!